# Spark - Java - Can't get JDBC type for array<string> when inserting to Oracle Array column type

Tags: java, oracle, apache-spark

I have a table in Oracle with a column as Array type. I received an exception when inserting dataframe to Oracle.

***Please note that this question is not about I should join with ", " and store as a string value in VARCHAR2 type column.***

Here is how I create this table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE dbObj_arr IS VARRAY (5) OF varchar2(6);

CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    "ID"        NUMBER,
    "Set"       dbObj_arr );

INSERT INTO MyTable ( ID, "Set" ) VALUES ( 1, dbObj_arr ('One', 'Two', 'Three') );  
INSERT INTO MyTable ( ID, "Set" ) VALUES ( 2, dbObj_arr ('Six', 'Seven') );
```

Here is how data are stored in the table.

[image]

**Exception**

```
+---+---------------+
|Id |CSV            |
+---+---------------+
|1  |One, Two, Three|
|2  |Six, Seven     |
+---+---------------+

root
 |-- Id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- CSV: string (nullable = true)

+---+-----------------+
|Id |Set              |
+---+-----------------+
|1  |[One, Two, Three]|
|2  |[Six, Seven]     |
+---+-----------------+

root
 |-- Id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Set: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

21/02/25 16:42:26 WARN JdbcUtils: Requested isolation level 1 is not supported; falling back to default isolation level 2
21/02/25 16:42:26 WARN JdbcUtils: Requested isolation level 1 is not supported; falling back to default isolation level 2
21/02/25 16:42:26 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for array<string>
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$getJdbcType$2(JdbcUtils.scala:188)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.getJdbcType(JdbcUtils.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$savePartition$5(JdbcUtils.scala:663)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$savePartition$5$adapted(JdbcUtils.scala:663)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:663)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$saveTable$1(JdbcUtils.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$saveTable$1$adapted(JdbcUtils.scala:856)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:994)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:994)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2139)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
21/02/25 16:42:26 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
```

**Sample Code**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.split;

public class SampleArrayApp implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
    
    private static String DbFormat = "jdbc";
    private static String DbUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@oved1070.vmpc1.cloud.boeing.com:53620:BBLFSDEV";
    private static String DbUser = "STAGING";
    private static String DbPassword = "St@Ging";
    private static String DbDriver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
    private static String DbTable  = "MyTable";
    
    private static String ID = "Id";
    private static String CSV = "CSV";
    private static String SET = "Set";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SampleArrayApp app = new SampleArrayApp();
        app.start();
    }

    private void start() {

        Logger.getLogger("org.apache").setLevel(Level.WARN);

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Spark App")
                .master("local[*]")
                .getOrCreate();

        StructType structType = new StructType();
        structType = structType.add(ID, DataTypes.IntegerType, false);
        structType = structType.add(CSV, DataTypes.StringType, true);
        
        List<Row> list = new ArrayList<Row>();
        list.add(RowFactory.create(1, "One, Two, Three"));
        list.add(RowFactory.create(2, "Six, Seven"));       
                
        Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(list, structType);
        df.show(10, false);     
        df.printSchema();
        
        Dataset<Row> resultDf = df
                .withColumn(SET, split(col(CSV), ", "))
                .drop(col(CSV));
        
        resultDf.show(10, false);       
        resultDf.printSchema();
        
        performInsert(resultDf);
    }
    

    private void performInsert(Dataset<Row> df) {
        
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", DbUser);
        props.setProperty("password", DbPassword);
        props.setProperty("driver", DbDriver);

        df.write()
            .mode(SaveMode.Append)
            .jdbc(DbUrl, DbTable, props);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not supported, see: [JDBC OracleDialect](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4d428a821b2117789d0a2c61c7229d00af1704eb/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/OracleDialect.scala#L71)

Answer (score 0):

There is no dataframe API. However, we can iterate each row and insert them manually - it is slow and not optimal.

```
private void insert(Dataset<Row> df) {      
    
    df.coalesce(df.javaRDD().getNumPartitions())
        .foreachPartition(new ForeachPartitionFunction<Row>() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void call(Iterator<Row> t) throws Exception {
            
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("user", "USERNAME");
            props.setProperty("password", "PASSWORD");
            props.setProperty("driver", "jdbc");    
            
            Connection conn = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            
            int batchSize = BATCH_SIZE;
                
            try {
                DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("URL", props);
                stmt = conn.createStatement();                          

                int currentBatchSize = 0;
                    
                while (t.hasNext()) {
                    Row row = t.next();
                    
                    String id = row.getAs(ID).toString();
                    String names = row.getAs(NAMES).toString(); // Comma separated names
                                
                    String sql = "DECLARE names EFFOBJ := EFFOBJ(" + names  + "); "
                            + "BEGIN INSERT INTO TABLENAME (ID, NAMES) "
                            + "VALUES (" + id + ", names); END;";
                    stmt.addBatch(sql);
                    
                    currentBatchSize++;

                    if (!t.hasNext() || currentBatchSize == 5000) {
                        stmt.executeBatch();
                        currentBatchSize = 0;
                    }                                               
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (stmt != null)
                    stmt.close();
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
            }
        }
    });
}
```